# Adding InputBox entry to existing number in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want my InputBox to add to an existing number.

```
Sub Addnumber ()
Dim number As Variant
number = InputBox("Enter number")
Range("D4").Value = number
End Sub
```

So if the number 4 is already in cell D4 and I write 4 in the inputbox, then I want 8 in D4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would validate if both cell value and the input are numbers, then add the two and output the result.

EDIT: Added variations for working with specific range or current selected cell. Thanks to @JvdV for pointing out the Application.Inputbox parameters...

EDIT2: As @JvdV pointed out, it's better to full qualify the range if you're working with an specific range (then this line: `Set evalCell = Range("D4")` should be something like `Set evalCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your sheet").Range("D4")`)

**Specific Range:**

```
Public Sub AddNumberSpecificRange()
    Dim number As Variant
    Dim evalCell As Range
    number = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter number", Type:=1)
    Set evalCell = Range("D4")
    If IsNumeric(evalCell.Value) And IsNumeric(number) Then
        evalCell.Value = evalCell.Value + number
    End If
End Sub
```

**Working with selected cell:**

```
Public Sub AddNumberActiveCell()
    Dim number As Variant
    number = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter number", Type:=1)
    If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + number
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Using `Application.InputBox` method would be able to specify `Type` parameter to `1`, being a numerical input =). Could be handy to know for OP. Small sidenote, it could be handy to be `Explicit` about your sheet reference.

Comment: Thanks for that @JvdV. 
I have one question if you don't mind. What if I want to use my activecell instead D4? How do I write the code then. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks to @JvdV for pointing out the Application.Inputbox parameters. See my edit

Comment: @RicardoDIaz Hi Ricardo. Thanks a lot for the EDIT! However, it does give an error with "Expected Function or Variable" at `If IsNumeric(Activecell.Value)`

Comment: Hi @Christian did the first one work? sounds like a typo in the formula.

Comment: Hi @RicardoDiaz yes the first one worked like a charm!

Comment: @Christian works on my end. could you please copy and paste here in the comments the complete line that is raising the error.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz sorry it works now. I have no clue why it didnt before. Thanks a lot Ricardo :D